# Emails on discussion board via workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow, email, discussion-board

I have a discussion board with a person column called as "**Reviewer**" in a discussion board. I want to set-up sending emails on a discussion board when:

1. A mail to reviewer when he/she is added to comment on a discussion.
2. A mail to creator, when reviewer replies to a discussion.
3. A mail to reviewer if he does not responds in 7 days.